# Expression must have integral or unscoped enum tupe

Tags: c++

I'm writing a console app that takes in the netprice of a product and prints out the gross price, while working on main, I can across an issue where I get an `expression must have integral or unscoped enum type` error on lines `cout << "Software costs " + product[0]->getGrossPrice();` & `cout << "Book costs " + product[1]->getGrossPrice();`

Here is the what I wrote so far:

```
#include "Software.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "Product.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double price;

    vector<Product*> product(8);

    Software *software;
    Book *book;

    cout << "Enter price of software";
    cin >> price;

    product[0] = new Software(price);

    cout << "Software costs " + product[0]->getGrossPrice();

    cout << "Enter price of book";
    cin >> price;

    product[1] = new Book(price);

    cout << "Book costs " + product[1]->getGrossPrice();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ~

Comment: `cout << "Software costs " << product[0]->getGrossPrice();` As originally written, you are trying to add a `double` to a string literal, which makes no sense.

Comment: It looks like your vector's pointers have ownership of what they point to. Additionally, it looks like `Product` is a polymorphic type. So while using pointers is correct, you should consider using a smart pointer like `unique_ptr` instead. For example `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Product>>`.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now.... 

Thanks a lot! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of initializing your vector to 8 unused elements with `vector<Product*> product(8);`, you can just create an empty vector with `vector<Product*> product;` and add elements as you go with `product.emplace_back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ostream& operator <<` is the best option for this, since it's overloaded to accept any primitive types and convert them to string streams. Using + for different types usually doesn't work very well.

Replace

```
cout << "Software costs " + product[0]->getGrossPrice();
```

With

```
cout << "Software costs " << product[0]->getGrossPrice();
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is operator precedence, this line

```cpp
cout << "Software costs " + product[0]->getGrossPrice();
```

Is actually this:

```cpp
cout << ("Software costs " + product[0]->getGrossPrice());
```

So you are trying add string literal and something what can't be added to string literal.